# SQLAlchemy Query - Incorrect Count

Tags: python, session, sqlalchemy, arguments

I'm having some trouble formatting this query with sqlalchemy. I'm trying to return the correct count, but it keeps returning 0

Here is the code snippet for it:

```
        with Session(self.engine) as session:
            statement = func.count(distinct(*columns)).label("time_off_task_count")

            # data = session.query(statement).where(Events.event_start >= start if start is not None else None,
            #                                         Events.event_end < end if end is not None else None,
            #                                         Events.dc == dc if dc is not None else None,
            #                                         Events.brand == brand if brand is not None else None,
            #                                         Events.event_source == "Time Off Task").all()
            data = session.query(statement).where(Events.event_source == "Time Off Task").all()                                        

        for row in data:
            return int(row.time_off_task_count)
```

Does anyone know how to fix the query?

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what your ternary operators do.

```py
Events.event_start >= start if start is not None else None
```

Gives

```py
Events.event_start >= start
```

if `start` is not `None`, otherwise it gives

```py
None
```

Demo:

```py
1 > 0 if True else None  # True
1 > 0 if False else None  # None
```

And filtering with `None` gives `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE NULL` which will select nothing.

So you need to change how you are filtering, the following should work, however you provided no data so I could not test it.

```py
statement = select(*columns).distinct().filter(Events.event_source == "Time Off Task")
if start is not None:
    statement = statement.filter(Events.event_start >= start)
if end is not None:
    statement = statement.filter(Events.event_end < end)
if dc is not None:
    statement = statement.filter(Events.dc == dc)
if brand is not None:
    statement = statement.filter(Events.brand == brand)
statement = func.count(statement)
```

Comment: Thank you, that explanation makes more sense. I did need to reformat the query though. It ended up being:

Comment: `statement = func.count(distinct(*columns))
            data = session.query(statement.label("time_off_task_count"))
            for query in filter_queries:
                data = data.filter(query)`

Comment: Where `filter_queries` is the list of Binary Expressions for filtering